# Getting the text from all p elements in a div with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the text (contents without the tags) of all p elements in a given div:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getArticle(url):
    url = 'http://www.bbc.com/news/business-34421804'
    result = requests.get(url)
    c = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c)

    article = []
    article = soup.find("div", {"class":"story-body__inner"}).findAll('p')
    for element in article:
        article = ''.join(element.findAll(text = True))
    return article
```

The problem is that this returns only the contents of the last paragraph. But the code works perfectly if I just use print:

```
    for element in article:
        print ''.join(element.findAll(text = True))
    return
```

I want to call this function elsewhere, so I need it to return the text, not just print it. I have searched stackoverflow and googled a lot, but didn't find the answer and I don't understand what might be the problem. I use Python 2.7.9 and bs4.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following code should work -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getArticle(url):
    url = 'http://www.bbc.com/news/business-34421804'
    result = requests.get(url)
    c = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c)

    article_text = ''
    article = soup.find("div", {"class":"story-body__inner"}).findAll('p')
    for element in article:
        article_text += '\n' + ''.join(element.findAll(text = True))
    return article_text
```

There are a couple of issues in your code -

1. Same variable name 'article' has been used to store the elements as well as the text.
2. The variable that should be returned is only being assigned the value and not appended, so only last value remains in that.

Answer (score 0):

To get all text from the article (`CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), have a look at [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser):

```py
for text in soup.select('.ssrcss-xalfp3-ArticleWrapper div > div > p'):
   article_text = text.text
   # other code
```

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}


def get_news_article():
  html = requests.get("https://www.bbc.com/news/business-34421804", headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

  title = soup.select_one('#main-heading').text
  print(f'Title: {title}\n')

  for text in soup.select('.ssrcss-xalfp3-ArticleWrapper div > div > p'):
    article_text = text.text
    print(article_text)
    print()

  return article_text

get_news_article()

---------------
'''
Title: Amazon bars the sale of Apple and Google TV devices

Amazon is to stop selling video-streaming TV devices from Google and Apple because they don't "interact well" with its own media service.

The online retailer said it had made the decision to avoid "customer confusion" and the devices will be removed from sale by 29 October.

... other text
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    def getArticle(url):
        url = 'http://www.bbc.com/news/business-34421804'
        result = requests.get(url)
        c = result.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(c)
    
        article = []
        article_total = []
        for i in range(len( soup.find("div", {"class":"story-body__inner"}))):
            article = soup.find("div", {"class":"story-body__inner"})[i].findAll('p')
            for element in article:
                article = ''.join(element.findAll(text = True))
            article_total.append(article)
    article_total
```